# Install DeepSpeech on Mac M1

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech

At the moment I need to install and run DeepSpeech on my local.

Can someone help me how with installing DeepSpeech on my Mac. I have already installed Python 3.10.0 but it seems like this version do not work with DeepSeech

Comment: Do you have ARM architecture? I am trying to build the binary from source but still failed